# Button enable disble on select dropdown Value

Tags: javascript, jquery, button, dropdown

I have two Buttons:

1. For bulk order
2. For sample Order

By default both buttons are disabled when I click on the dropdown. Value "1" then "Sample order Btn" should be enabled and when I click on the dropdown value more then 1 "Buk Order" Btn should be enabled.

On select again both buttons should be disabled.
Here is my code on select element, it doesn't work and I don't know why.

```js
$("select").on('change',function(){
    if ($(this).find('option:selected').text()=="1"){
        alert('1');
        $("#product-addtocart-button").attr('disabled',true);
        $("#product-addtocart-button1").attr('disabled',false);
    }
  
    if ($(this).find('option:selected').text()!="1" && $(this).find('option:selected').text()!="0"){
        alert('25');
        $("#product-addtocart-button1").attr('disabled',true);
        $("#product-addtocart-button").attr('disabled',false);
    }
    
    if ($(this).find('option:selected').text()=="0"){
        alert('sele');
        $("#product-addtocart-button").attr('disabled',true);
        $("#product-addtocart-button1").attr('disabled',true);
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="productextra">
    <option selected value="0">select</option>
    <option value="1">1</option>
    <option value="25">25</option>
    <option value="50">50</option>
    <option value="75">75</option>
    <option value="100">100</option>
    <option value="150">150</option>
    <option value="200">200</option>
    <option value="250">250</option>
    <option value="300">300</option>
    <option value="400">400</option>
    <option value="500">500</option>
    <option value="750">750</option>
    <option value="1000">1000</option>
</select>
<button type="button" id="product-addtocart-button" class="button btn-cart"  disabled="disabled">
    <span>
        <span>Bulk Order</span>
    </span>
</button>
<button type="button" id="product-addtocart-button1" class="button btn-cart select-change" disabled="disabled">
    <span>
        <span>Sample Order</span>
    </span>
</button>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
$("select").on('change', function() {

  console.log($('option:selected', this).text() == 0)
  console.log($('option:selected', this).val())
  $("#product-addtocart-button").attr('disabled', $('option:selected', this).val() > 1 || $('option:selected', this).val() == 0);
  $("#product-addtocart-button1").attr('disabled', $('option:selected', this).val() == 1 || $('option:selected', this).val() == 0);


});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="productextra">
  <option selected value="0">select</option>
  <option value="1">1</option>
  <option value="25">25</option>
  <option value="50">50</option>
  <option value="75">75</option>
  <option value="100">100</option>
  <option value="150">150</option>
  <option value="200">200</option>
  <option value="250">250</option>
  <option value="300">300</option>
  <option value="400">400</option>
  <option value="500">500</option>
  <option value="750">750</option>
  <option value="1000">1000</option>
</select>
<button type="button" id="product-addtocart-button" class="button btn-cart" disabled="disabled"><span><span>Bulk Order</span></span>
</button>
<button type="button" id="product-addtocart-button1" class="button btn-cart select-change" disabled="disabled"><span><span>Sample Order</span></span>
</button>
```

Use value and compare to 1 or 0 depending on result disable or enable the button

Comment: @AditiPatel glad to help mate happy coding :)

Answer (score 0):

USE

```
$("#product-addtocart-button").attr('disabled','disabled');
$("#product-addtocart-button1").removeAttr('disabled');
```

INSTEAD OF

```
$("#product-addtocart-button").attr('disabled',true);
$("#product-addtocart-button1").attr('disabled',false);
```